# Как организовать несколько циклов?

Tags: c++, циклы

Делаю простейшие задачи.
Проблема в том, что я пока не знаю, как сделать множественный цикл (т.е. ввел переменные, получил результат и все, программа завершается, а я хочу повторить несколько раз, не закрывая окно, проверить, насколько корректно она работает при разных значениях переменных)
Пример.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int H, A, B;
    cin >> H >>A >> B;
    cout << (H + A - 2 * B - 1) / (A-B);
    return 0;
}
```

p.s. глупый вопрос, но ответа я пока не вижу, а задачи идут подряд, хочу сразу оптимизировать.

UPD
В итоге собрал вот так, наиболее понятная пока для меня версия, спасибо всем, кто предложил свой вариант

```
int main() {

    char ans = '1';
    while (ans == '1')
    {
        int H, A, B;
        cin >> H >> A >> B;
        cout << "result     " << (H + A + B) << endl;
        cout << "     " << endl;
        cout << "Repeat: 1, exit: other button";
        cin >> ans;
    }
```

}

Comment: Не понял вопрос. По каким переменным вы хотите сделать цикл? От какого до какого значения эти переменные должны меняться?

Comment: По сути я просто хочу чтобы программа продолжала работать после того, как я один раз ввел переменные и получил результат. Например, здесь чтобы я мог много раз вводить H, A, B и получать результат для каждой, не перезапуская окно.

Comment: Что такое "множественный цикл" и чем он отличается от обычного цикла?

Comment: Это слово, которое я выбрал когда писал вопрос, не более того.

Comment: Это прекрасно, но что это слово значит? У вас в вопросе речь идет о "множественных циклах" и "нескольких циклов". Зачем в этой задаче вам понадобились "несколько циклов"? Для чего?

Answer (score 4):

```
for(;;)
{
    int H, A, B;
    if (!(cin >> H >> A >> B)) break;
    cout << (H + A - 2 * B - 1) / (A-B) << endl;
}
```

Как надоест - нажмете Ctrl-Z (Ctrl-D в Linux). Или введете не число...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Да, конечно! Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Это очень грубая, студенческая реализация, которая возможно будет более понятной начинающему разработчику на С++.

```
int main()
{
int h, a, b;
bool out = true;
while (out) 
{
    std::cout << "Input your numbers: ";
    std::cin >> h >> a >> b;
    std::cout << "Result = " << (h + a - 2 * b - 1) / (a - b) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Repeat again? y/n" << std::endl;
    std::string answer = "";
    std::cin >> answer;
    if (answer == "n")
        out = false;
}
return 0;
}
```

Только нужно добавить `#include <string>`.